# Difference between kill -28 and apache graceful stop

Tags: apache

It is correct to say that running these 2 commands will result in the same outcome - graceful stop?

```
kill -28 [apache_pid]
```

and

```
apachectl -k graceful-stop
```

According to the [apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/stopping.html#gracefulstop) and this [stackoverflow question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317492/list-of-kill-signals) I am leaning towards yes. `kill -28` sends the winch signal to apache which is the equivalent as using the apachectl cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing this, I can confirm that the to commands result in the same outcome. They both result in a graceful restart.

Comment: This is actually implemented near https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/include/mpm_common.h#L70 and the `-k graceful-stop` indeed just signals `SIGWINCH` which is `28` in practice.